# eclipse mars: no option to create new server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-mars

I am trying to configure tomcat server on my Eclipse IDE (Mars). I could not find any option to install server.

Some links I have referred to are below:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fconfiguration.html

screenshots of my IDE.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayJTk.png

Answer (score 2):

Download eclipse [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and make sure you have the version "**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**". I think you installed "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".

Left click on "Project Explorer" -> "New" -> "Other"

On the new Window -> expand "Server" -> "Server"